# Cannot put cursor in front of a non-contenteditable div in a contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

So here is my layout

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  ///
  <div contenteditable=false>not editable</div>
  ///
</div>
```

I have one issue, when the non-contenteditable div is the first element of a new line, I cannot place the cursor in front of the div by using arrow keys or clicking in front of the div.

I've tried every solution posted here but none worked and all had the same issue, wondering how this is solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to put a zero width character before the div - but if the non editable element is one that causes a line break you'll have to put one of those in as well.

Obviously definitely not ideal as it adds a character to the editable code which you'll have to deal with later on

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  ///<br>
 &#x200B;<div contenteditable=false style="display: inline-block;">not editable</div>
  ///
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why i cannot remove it. The non-editable div cannot be placed at the previous line?.

Comment: I've ended up placing a `&zwj;` entity but it ran into another issue, i need to press the back and forward keys twice in order to be infront or after the entity. Any reason for this?

Comment: @AhmedKhattab probably because that zero-width joiner is still considered a "character", and so you need one additional cursor-left or -right to "get past it."

Comment: does not work in firefox :(