How to put cursor in between br and non-contenteditable?
Here is the HTML


<div contenteditable="true" style="padding: 8px;">
  hello world
  <br>
  <div contenteditable="false" style="display: inline-block;">hello world</div>
</div>



I'm not able to put the cursor beginning of the non-contenteditable here (or in between the br and non-contenteditable). Please give me HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that will do this.
What I tried: 0-width space in between br and non-contenteditable. I don't like this because you have to press extra arrows to move around. And you have to remove the 0-width space every time you remove the non-contenteditable.

Hey, can you give a bit more context? what exactly do you mean by "put the cursor at the beginning"? And "have to press extra arrows to move around"?

The 2 'hello world's appear on different lines. You able to put your cursor just right of the 'd' on both lines and left of the 'h' on the 1st line. You can't place the cursor just left of the 2nd 'h'. The 0-width space solution is referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69910603/cannot-put-cursor-in-front-of-a-non-contenteditable-div-in-a-contenteditable-div. Sorry for the confusion.

What do you mean by "non-contenteditable"? The <br> is immediately followed by the contenteditable div, there's nothing in between them.

You should be able to copy and paste the code into jsfiddle to play around with it.

You able to put your cursor in between the 'd' and the  but not the  and the non-contenteditable . @Barmar

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this allows to put the cursor at the 2nd "H":
`
hello world

hello world 

`
That didn't work for me.

Have a look at this doc

It doesn't seem like in between the br and the non-contenteditable is a valid index. In between 2 br's seems fine as well as 2 non-contenteditable's for some reason.

@solidwaterslayer FYI, you don't need to tell people to create a fiddle on their own, you can use the Stack Snippet functionality (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1427878) - I edited your question to transform the code block into one.

This makes perfect sense as you can only place the carret inside text nodes to begin with, and the d is part of a text node, so the cursor will be placed at the end of that node. A br is not a text node, and the next text node is not editable. This is expected behaviour.

I'm not sure why you able to put your cursor in between two 's and two non-contenteditable. And in between a non-contenteditable followed by a . But for some reason, you can't for  followed by non-contenteditable. @somethinghere

I didn't find out how to make it without a 0-width space, but maybe you can try to skip the 0-width space automatically when moving the caret and delete it when deleting nodes next to it.
Here's what I tried to handle the caret when pressing arrow keys (codepen, in Firefox you can't position the caret after a non-contenteditable at the end of the editable parent, so I added an extra 0-width space at the end):
editable.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const position = selection.getRangeAt(0)
  
  if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    if (position.startOffset === 1 && position.startContainer.textContent.startsWith('\u200b')) {
        createSelection(position.startContainer.previousSibling, true)
    }
  }
  
  if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
    if (position.startOffset === 0 && position.startContainer.textContent.startsWith('\u200b')) {
      selection.collapse(position.startContainer, 1)
    }
  }
})

function createSelection(element) {
  const newSelection = window.getSelection();
  newSelection.removeAllRanges();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(element);
  newSelection.addRange(range);
}

Sadly it didn't work very well, and I haven't worked out how to delete the 0-width space automatically.

Yeah, that's what I did. I added a zero-width character and wrote some code to skip over them that also doesn't work very well :( I was wondering if this is a bug in the HTML :(

The reason why mines also doesn't work very well is b/c FireFox likes to be special :(
